# dynamic value for ng-style inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Need to apply dynamic css, but ng-style is not working if i try to create style variable with ng-repeat, if i replace value of ng-style with constant it is working fine,

```
<span ng-repeat="val in value">
  <label ng-style="'class'+val">
    {{val}}
    <input type="checkbox" class ="pull-right"/>
  </label>
</span>
```

Can you please help.

Comment: I don't think you want ng-style.  You seem to need to apply a class based off of the value.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to apply a class, then you should be using `ng-class`(*I'm just wondering how it got work with constant?*)

```
ng-class="'class'+val"
```

---

If you wanted to apply style on element then it would have been either like

```
ng-style="{color: val}"
```

**OR**

```
ng-style="val"
```

Where val would have whole style JSON.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, guess you are correct, need to apply class.

Comment: @Learner you could accept answer, if it does helped, Thanks ;)